# Writing an iterated double integral in two forms

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

**Let $f\left(x,\:y\right)\:=\:x^2e^{x^2}$ and let $R$ be the triangle bounded by the lines $x=5$, $x=y/2$, and $y=x$ in the $xy$-plane.**

**Express $\int _RfdA$ in two different ways.**

After sketching the region, I got that the first way to write the integral would simply be:

$\int _0^5\int _x^{2x}\:x^2e^{x^2}dydx$

However, I was stuck on how to write it in the other way. With the region, there is no obvious way to write the integral as one in terms of $y$. I feel that this may mean that I need to have the sum of two different double integrals but I am not entirely sure how that would work in this case.

Would I have to subtract the higher $x=(1/2)y$ line from the $x=y$ line or is there some other way?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You have written it as a sum of weighted areas of vertical strips. The other way is to write it as a sum of weighted areas of horizontal strips. Indeed, you have it right that you should write it as the sum of two integrals and your sketch should tell you all you need to do so. One integral will have $x$ vary from the $y=2x$ line to the $y=x$ line and the other will have $x$ vary from the $y=2x$ line to the $x=5$ line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that the other expression has to be written as a sum of two integrals.  Sketching the region, we see that we can split the region into an upper and lower section.  The lower section is from $y = 0$ to $y = 5$, and the upper is from $y = 5$ to $y = 10$.  In this lower section, $x$ will vary from $y/2$ to $y$, and in the upper section, $x$ will vary from $y/2$ to $5$, since here $y > 5$ and the boundary becomes the vertical line $x = 5$.   Writing out the integral, we have 
$$
\int_{0}^{5}\int_{y/2}^{y} x^2 e^{x^2} dx dy + \int_{5}^{10} \int_{y/2}^{5} x^2 e^{x^2} dx dy .
$$